# Media Query in CSS file not running on IOS phone but runs fine in Android phone

Tags: ios, css, asp.net, media-queries

I have a css file that contains a media query for mobile devices under 992 px.
When I debug in Chrome on my desktop and I emulate all the different iphones and Android phones it runs the media query fine, when I open it on an actual Android phone it works fine too, but when I open it in a iPhone the media query doesn't run. Not sure why!

P.S. - I tried it on multiple iPhones thinking it might be a setting in Safari on my iPhone but have the same problem on 2 different iPhones.

Here is the media query in a css file

```
<link href="../library/reporting-media-query.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  #form1 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
  }
  #mainContainer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: .5em
  }
  #mainContainer select {
    font-size: 1.5em;
    width: 90%;
  }
  #mainContainer input[type=submit] {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 90% !important;
  }
  #mainContainer input[type=button] {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 90% !important;
  }
  #mainContainer input[type=radio] {
    font-size: 1em;
    width: 10% !important;
    height: 1em;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
// more CSS here but left out to save space
}
```

Comment: Did you add the viewport meta?

Comment: no, but I'm looking at another post that suggests this!

Comment: I tried adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> it's reading the media query, but it's not scaling correctly

Comment: Try adding this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: By the way have to use viewport meta to use media queries properly.